# FS file watcher, get changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to implement a file system watcher using node.js so that it watches a particular JSON file for changes.

And then, i would like to get what changed inside the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

- Load the current file contents and parse it to an object, keeping it in-memory.
- Watch for file changes, using [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener).
- On change, load the new file contents as an object.
- Perform an object diff between the current object and new object; e.g using [diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff).
- Set current object as new object.
- Repeat on change.

Here's an example:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const diff = require('deep-diff')

const filepath = './foo.json'
const getCurrent = () => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filepath, {
  encoding: 'utf8'
}))

let currObj = getCurrent()

fs.watch(filepath, { encoding: 'buffer' }, (eventType, filename) => {
  if (eventType !== 'change') return

  const newObj = getCurrent()
  const differences = diff(currObj, newObj)

  console.log(differences)
  // { kind: 'N' } for new key additions
  // { kind: 'E' } for edits
  // { kind: 'D' } for deletions

  currObj = newObj
})
```

Note that I'm using `fs.readFileSync` here for brevity. You should be better off using `fs.readFile` instead which is non-blocking.

Comment: I could not expect a better answer as that.
I still have one last question, how may i for instance console.log only one element of the path ?
Thanks in advance ! =)

Comment: What do you mean "one element of the path"? What's the path and what's an element?

Comment: When i am modifying something in my json file, it is returning something like this :
https://i.imgur.com/gs7Jiir.png
How may i for instance, console.log only "path", or even better, "buy" which is in the path.

Comment: @Zayonx That's the diff returned by the [diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff) module I've included in my sample. You'd be better off reading it's docs.