# Emitting a socket.io event from Yii2 backend once an event fires

Tags: php, node.js, events, socket.io, yii2

I have a registration form. Once a user get registered, my `EVENT_AFTER_SIGNUP` event starts working. It has one function attached to it called `notificationEvent`. I also have socket.io listening on a port on that page, so inside my `notificationEvent` I want to emit a socket.io event. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how can I achieve this?
I am thinking about creating a text file with PHP which contains the emit code, and make a express event which listens for changes on that text file, and if it's changed then emit it's content.

**UPDATE**

After the `notificationEvent` is triggered i'm writing the user's name and surname in a text file, like so:

```
public function notificationEvent($event){

        $name = $event->sender->attributes['name'];
        $surname = $event->sender->attributes['surname'];
        $full = $name . " " . $surname . "\n";

        $sheet = fopen("../eventSheet", "a");
        fwrite($sheet, $full);
        fclose($sheet);
    }
```

And inside my Node JS code I'm looking for changes in that text file, like so:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const fs = require('fs');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('CONNECTED');

    fs.watch('../eventSheet',(curr, prev) =>{
        console.log(curr);
        console.log(prev)
    });

});

server.listen(3000);
```

console logging the `curr` gives me `change` and console logging `prev` gives me `EventSheet`, which is the name of my text file. I want to get the line which has been written into the file with PHP. How can I do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far? please share your code. please provide a [minimal reproducaple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Similar question has been answered before. Refer that,
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526027/2177996](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526027/2177996)